# Installing C++ NetCDF4 library on MacOS via MacPorts fails

Tags: c++, linker-errors, macports, netcdf4

I've installed netcdf-cxx4 via Macports and downloaded a C++ NetCDF4 example from here:
https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/examples/programs/SimpleXyWr.cpp

I'm rather unfamiliar with setting linking options and I tried to compile/link the program with the following command:

```
g++ SimpleXyWr.cpp -o SimpleXyWr.out -I/opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib -lnetcdf -lnetcdf_c++4
```

However, this results in the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__ZN6netCDF6NcFileC1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEENS0_8FileModeE", referenced from:
      _main in cco9p4yv.o
  "__ZNK6netCDF7NcGroup6addDimERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEm", referenced from:
      _main in cco9p4yv.o
  "__ZNK6netCDF7NcGroup6addVarERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKNS_6NcTypeERKSt6vectorINS_5NcDimESaISD_EE", referenced from:
      _main in cco9p4yv.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm quite clueless how to solve this problem.

**Update:** I partially solved the problem: I realised that MacPorts uses clang to compile the port. I therefore tried to install netcdf-cxx4 with the following command:

```
sudo port -s -v install netcdf-cxx4 configure.compiler=macports-gcc-10
```

The installation ends with:

```
netcdf-cxx4 is using libstdc++ (this installation is configured to use libc++)
--->  Found 1 broken port, determining rebuild order
You can always run 'port rev-upgrade' again to fix errors.
The following ports will be rebuilt: netcdf-cxx4 @4.3.0
Continue? [Y/n]:
```

If I type Y, netcdf-cxx4 is reinstalled (but again with clang - which does not help me). If I abort, I can use the NetCDF4 library (and everything seems to work). However, to solve the above issue, I tried installing netcdf-cxx4 with the command:

```
sudo port -s -v install netcdf-cxx4 configure.compiler=macports-gcc-10 configure.cxx_stdlib=macports-libstdc++
```

But this ends with the error message:

```
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_devel_gettext/gettext/work/gettext-0.19.8.1/gettext-runtime':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
configure: error: ./configure failed for gettext-runtime
Command failed:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_devel_gettext/gettext/work/gettext-0.19.8.1" && ./configure --prefix=/opt/local ac_cv_prog_AWK=/usr/bin/awk ac_cv_path_GREP=/usr/bin/grep ac_cv_path_SED=/usr/bin/sed --disable-csharp --disable-java --disable-native-java --disable-openmp --without-emacs --with-included-gettext --with-included-glib --with-included-libcroco --with-included-libunistring --with-included-libxml --without-cvs --without-git --without-xz 
Exit code: 77
Error: Failed to configure gettext, consult /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_devel_gettext/gettext/work/gettext-0.19.8.1/config.log
Error: Failed to configure gettext: configure failure: command execution failed
Error: See /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_devel_gettext/gettext/main.log for details.
Error: Unable to execute port: upgrade netcdf failed
```

What can I do to solve this? Thanks for any inputs!

Comment: Can you `grep` those libraries for the missing symbol names?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It seems that I narrowed down the reason of the issue (see update information above).

Answer (score 1):

You correctly deduced that the problem was that netcdf-cxx4 was compiled by MacPorts with clang++ whereas you were trying to compile your program with g++. clang++ uses the libc++ standard library while g++ uses the libstdc++ standard library; they're not compatible with one another. A C++ program and all of the libraries it uses must use the same C++ library.

Where you erred was in attempting to second-guess MacPorts' choice of compiler by overriding `configure.compiler` on the command line. MacPorts is not designed for you to do that. (The ability to override variables on the command line is intended for MacPorts developers to aid them in debugging problems.) Instead you should have done one of two things:

1. Let MacPorts compile netcdf-cxx4 with clang++ and compile your program with clang++ as well. This is the recommended option because clang is the preferred compiler on macOS. Or:
2. Run `port variants netcdf-cxx4` and discover that the author of the netcdf-cxx4 port has anticipated that you might want to compile it with different compilers and has provided variants that enable you to do so. For example, you could run `sudo port install netcdf-cxx4 +gcc10` to compile it with MacPorts gcc 10.